# .htaccess URL rewrite not working, tried all possible options

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was trying to rewrite a URL for making my site SEO friendly, but .htaccess rewrite not seems to work.

My URL is

www.tasteofkochi.com/dine-detail.php?a=150

I need this to look like

www.tasteofkochi.com/sometext/150

I did the simple formula but it's not reflecting, intact nothing happens at all. If I add some junk char in htaccess, site crashes, which means htaccess is working fine. Also I added a formula to remove .php extn, and that too works fine. Only issue is with this one. Can anyone please help me. I enable rewrite in httpd and allow all in directories, still not working.

Below is my .htacces

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9]+)/?$ dine-detail.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What are your current rules and what have you tried? Add that to your question.  Also what does some text before the number correspond to?

Comment: I have updated the htaccess in my post

Comment: @PanamaJack - could you please help.

Comment: @PanamaJack - please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

We can create pretty urls with .htaccess and php by mainly two files one is .htaccess and another index.php
[Example](http://qaify.com/blog/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess-and-php/)

Comment: Do we need both htaccess and php coding for URL prettify?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: yes @RohitMenon you need both .htaccess and php file.

Comment: i have gone through many articles, but no where its mentioned we need to use a php file as well.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

Comment: Can anyone please help?